# Using AWS Glue Schema Registry for Node.js or Ruby on Rails

Tags: aws-glue, aws-sdk-js, aws-msk, aws-sdk-ruby

Looking at the documentation for AWS Glue Schema Registry it seems like you can't use it for Node.js or Ruby on Rails:

> The AWS Glue Schema Registry supports AVRO (v1.10.2) data format and
> Java language support, with other data formats and languages to come
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/schema-registry.html
>
> Note Prerequisites: Before completing the following steps, you will
> need to have a Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK) or Apache
> Kafka cluster running. Your producers and consumers need to be running
> on Java 8 or above.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/schema-registry-gs.html

Has anyone had any luck using AWS Glue Schema Registry with Node.js or Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
https://github.com/meinestadt/glue-schema-registry

Might be the right choice for you if you plan to send or consume messages to/from Kafka or Kinesis with your node application.